# Las preposiciones "de", "a", "desde", "hasta" en fechas y tiempos

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, tiempo

Estoy despistado como usar las preposiciones. Yo tengo estas frases en mi libro de español:

1. Vivió en Alejandría de 2007 a 2010.
2. Desde 2011 vive en Barcelona.
3. Estudia sánscrito desde 2005.

No estoy seguro cuando es también correcto decir:

1. Vivió en Alejandría desde 2007 hasta 2010.
2. De 2011 vive en Barcelona.
3. Estudia sánscrito de 2005.

Mi maestro de español dice que con horas puedo decir:

1. La tienda está abierta de 8 a 5.
2. La tienda está abierta desde las 8 hasta las 2.

Tampoco estoy seguro si puedo decir:

1. La tienda está abierta de las 8 a las 5.
2. La tienda está abierta desde 8 hasta 5.

¿Puede alguien explicarme si existe una regla como usar esos preposiciones?

Comment: Ya que estás aprendiendo, me permito corregir una cosa más: no se dice *también no*, sino *tampoco*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La regla general es que puedes reemplazar `de ... a` por `desde ... hasta` (incluso para lugares, no solo para fechas y tiempos). Aunque dependiendo del contexto, uno puede ser ligeramente más idiomático que el otro, en general es correcto usar ambas opciones. La oración que mencionas

> Vivió en Alejandría desde 2007 hasta 2010.

es correcta.

Sin embargo, reemplazar `desde` (sin `hasta`) por `de` no es correcto. Por ejemplo, estas oraciones

> De 2011 vive en Barcelona.
>
> Estudia sánscrito de 2005.

son incorrectas.

Sobre las horas, la regla general es que siempre hay que añadir artículo, por ejemplo `la una`, `las tres`. Por ejemplo la oración

> La tienda está abierta desde 8 hasta 5.

es incorrecta.

Si usas `de ... a`, es un caso especial en el cual es idiomático omitir el artículo. La oración

> La tienda está abierta de las 8 a las 5.

no es incorrecta, pero se suele preferir omitir el artículo si usas `de ... a`, de manera similar a como el español también tiende a omitir pronombres en varias oraciones. Esto sería más idiomático:

> La tienda está abierta de 8 a 5.

Similar al caso de las fechas, si solo indicas inicio, no puedes usar `de`. Por ejemplo, estas oraciones

> La tienda está abierta de las 8.
>
> La tienda está abierta de 8.

son incorrectas. Si solo indicas inicio, debes usar `desde`. La oración

> La tienda está abierta desde las 8.

es correcta.

Comment: Creo que coloquialmente es aceptable: *La tienda está abierta de las 8.*

Comment: @Gustavson ¿No será muy rioplatense eso? Para mí está bien coloquialmente pero no creo que sea recomendable.

Comment: No digo que sea recomendable: sólo coloquialmente aceptable (y sí, puede que sólo por estas latitudes). Habría que ahondar un poco...

Comment: ¿Reemplazar `hasta` (sin `desde`) por `a` es también incorrecto?
Creo que es correcto decir: `Vivió allí hasta 2007.` y `La tienda está abierta hasta las 8.`. Creo que NO es correcto decir: `Vivió allí a 2007.` ni `La tienda está abierta a 8.`. ¿Tengo razón?

Comment: @Jenicek , tienes razón. Incluso coloquialmente, tampoco he escuchado gente que reemplace `hasta` (sin `desde`) por `a`. Usar solo `hasta` (sin `desde`) para indicar solo el fin de algo sí es correcto y comúnmente usado.